# Reduce Visual Studio's memory limit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a project and I'd like to trigger some memory exceptions to see where they occur without having to load 2GB files. how do I do that?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. What do you mean by "Visual Studio's memory limit"?

Comment: I think the reference is to the 32-bit user space memory limit for running programs and confusion between the IDE and the application giving the error.

Comment: Do you mean "out of memory exception?"  If not, what "memory exceptions" do you mean?

Comment: @dauphic: I mean the memory that the program can use.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, I mean the OOM exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just run a quick loop allocating blocks of memory until exhausted.

```
void* p;
do {
  p = malloc (1024 * 1024);
} while (p != NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talk about the 2GB limit of 32 bit Windows. If you do - this might do the trick:

just pre-allocate some memory up front to generate some base load e.g.

```
struct memwaste
{
  char* m_ptr;
  memwaste() : m_ptr(new char[1024*1024*104]) {} //waste 1 gb
  ~memwaste() { delete[] m_ptr }
}x;
```

add this struct to your code somewhere and it "wastes" some memory (aka baseload). Now you can run your program. Eventually it will run into problems allocating memory.

The baseload of memwast has to be adapted to your needs of course - it depends on where you want to check the memory allocation errors.

Comment: You should fill the memory, to be sure the OS isn't doing anything "smart" behind you, like "not really allocating the memory but only allocating the address space". Read "overcommit" on Linux. You can't be sure MS won't do it tomorrow.

Comment: interesting strategy - but I don't think it's a good one. Still it's easy to fix, just call memset inside the constructor.

Comment: The 2GB limit has nothing to do with overcommitting, but address space. You're still using address space and will hit the limit if the memory pages aren't backed by real memory.